# How to send a response code as a response in Akka Http?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have the below code:

```
val route:Route={
    path("hello"){
      get{
        complete{
          "done"
        }
      }
    }
  }

  Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8187)
```

Here the complete responds back with string "done". However, I want it to return a status code of 200. How can I do this?

Comment: It actually returns a HTTP 200 code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As explained in the comments the default response code is 200, so you're getting exactly what you wanted.  In general, [the documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/route-directives/complete.html#complete) on `complete` demonstrates how to write a `complete` with any status code:

```
complete(StatusCodes.OK)

complete(StatusCodes.Create -> "message")

complete(201 -> "another message")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use HttpResponse class

```
 import akka.http.scaladsl.model._

 complete{
    HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, entity = "Result ok")
   //HttpResponse(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, entity = "Error") 
  }
```